# Google App Engine returns "Error: FORBIDDEN" for anything except root

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I've just deployed [my first app FTheme.com](http://www.ftheme.com) that works smooth on dev server but now it shows `403 Error: FORBIDDEN` for any page except root. Here is the sample server response:

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
Date: Sun, 06 Feb 2011 14:07:09 GMT
Server: Google Frontend
Cache-Control: private, x-gzip-ok=""
Content-Length: 166

<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>403 FORBIDDEN</title>
</head>
<body text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff>
<h1>Error: FORBIDDEN</h1>
</body></html>
```

I event get this on JSP pages that do no more than simple includes and simple code like `req.getParameter()`.

Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: How do you map urls to servlets/JSPs? (post your web.xml)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[I've found the problem, JSP mapping did not work on deployment but work locally.](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-java/browse_thread/thread/71d5c8e4671cb044)